# Meaning of uint32:0 in dbus-send and bash syntax

Tags: bash, d-bus

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply           \
   --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus             \
   /org/freedesktop/DBus                   \
   org.freedesktop.DBus.StartServiceByName \
   string:org.freedesktop.login1 uint32:0  \
   2>&1 > /dev/null
```

I saw this `dbus` command used to launch [logind](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/).

Questions:

1. Why does [dbus-send](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/system-activation.txt) have the term `uint32:0`? What does it
   do? What does :0 mean?
2. Should `2>&1 > /dev/null` be rewritten as `1> /dev/null` given the purpose of the former is to only display error msg?

Comment: Note that it is literally `uint32`, not `unit`, as in your question title and body. This refers to the data type, a 32-bit *u*nsigned *int*eger, he value of which is to be set to `0`.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks. Corrected typo. Why does this command need to assign an unsigned 32bit zero value to this `dbus-send` cmd?

Answer (score 0):

From the man page (D-Bus 1.14.6):

```
NAME
       dbus-send - Send a message to a message bus

SYNOPSIS
       dbus-send [--system | --session | --bus=ADDRESS | --peer=ADDRESS] [--sender=NAME] [--dest=NAME] [--print-reply [=literal]] [--reply-timeout=MSEC]
                 [--type=TYPE] OBJECT_PATH INTERFACE.MEMBER [CONTENTS...]
```

So decomposing your command:

- `--system`: use the system bus (as opposed to the session bus)
- `--dest=org.freedesktop.DBus`: send to the service on the bus that has registered the name `org.freedesktop.DBus`
- `/org/freedesktop/DBus` (`OBJECT_PATH`): where to direct the DBus message within the service
- `org.freedesktop.DBus.StartServiceByName` (`INTERFACE.MEMBER`): call the function `StartServiceByName` from the interface `org.freedesktop.DBus`
- `string:org.freedesktop.login1`, `uint32:0` are `[CONTENTS...]`

From the man page again:

```
[The message contents] are given as type-specified values and may include containers (arrays, dicts, and variants) as described below.

   <contents>   ::= <item> | <container> [ <item> | <container>...]
   <item>       ::= <type>:<value>
   <container>  ::= <array> | <dict> | <variant>
   <array>      ::= array:<type>:<value>[,<value>...]
   <dict>       ::= dict:<type>:<type>:<key>,<value>[,<key>,<value>...]
   <variant>    ::= variant:<type>:<value>
   <type>       ::= string | int16 | uint16 | int32 | uint32 | int64 | uint64 | double | byte | boolean | objpath
```

So there both have the form `<item>` which is `<type>:<value>`, specifically:

- `string:org.freedesktop.login1`: the string `"org.freedesktop.login1"`
- `uint32:0`: the 32-bit unsigned integer `0`

Now to know what those mean, you should refer to the [freedesktop spec on StartServiceByName](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#bus-messages-start-service-by-name):

> Tries to launch the executable associated with a name (service activation), as an explicit request. This is an alternative to relying on auto-starting. For more information on how services are activated and the difference between auto-starting and explicit activation, see the section called “Message Bus Starting Services (Activation)”.

It also details the arguments:

> Message arguments:
>
> | Argument | Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | STRING | Name of the service to start |
> | 1 | UINT32 | Flags (currently not used) |

So this `dbus-send` command is requesting the start of the `login1` service. **The `uint32:0` means no flags are set, but currently no flags are defined, so it has no meaning at all.**

As to `2>&1 > /dev/null`, the short answer is that it could be rewritten `&> /dev/null` not `1> /dev/null`. It is specifying to redirect stderr to the same stream as stdout (`2>&1`) and to redirect stdout to `/dev/null` (`> /dev/null`, which is the same as `1>/dev/null`), so **both streams are discarded.** For more on redirects, you should probably look at [*Redirections in bash*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), the bash manual page on redirections.